# COCOA: cursor not jumping to next control on tab press

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa

Here is my form:

[image]

Cursor is jumping fine from *First Name* fo *Phone* but when I press TAB on phone it goes to *First Name* instead of *Country*

I have set the `NextKeyView` but still its not going to country when pressing TAB on *Phone* Feild

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hit `ctrl+F7` and try again. You may not have keyboard navigation enabled (as a user), which may skip the pop up.

[image: screenshot]
<sub>(source: [weba11y.com](http://www.weba11y.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/MacKbdNav.jpg))</sub>

Comment: can I enable keyboard navigation on programmatically?? or for specific form??

Comment: I don't think so, and I don't think you should. This is a user setting; leave it alone. It is sometimes hard for nerds like us to understand, but not everybody uses computers like we do. Follow the principle of least surprise and behave like every other app.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the following from System Preferences:

OSX lets the cursor stop only on text fields not on listbox or popup buttons. This is an expected behaviour and rarely someone tries to change it.

You can change this behaviour but that would be a bad UX since this change will affect all the applications in the system.

[image]

Comment: can I enable keyboard navigation on programmatically?? or for specific form??

Comment: @VikasBansal: I updated the answer. BTW the answer is YES, but you should not do.